Why does a router need to have an IP assigned to be able to handle Proxy ARP?
This is basically a follow up question of this one. I've had many great answers, but I am failing to understand specifically when people say that you need an IP address assigned to perform Proxy ARP.
I don't intend to discuss whether using Proxy ARP is a good idea or not, but for the sake of this question, let's assume that I found a scenario where Proxy ARP would be the best option or that the cons of using it are negligible or acceptable, etc.
Let's also assume we had a network like this one:
A --- R --- B

I'm going to name the network interfaces of each device using this convention: eth_X_Y

X = device that owns the network interface
Y = device the network interface is connected to.
A: The client device that wants to talk to the server (B). Its network interface is called eth_a_r. Its IP address is 1.1.1.1 and its MAC address is 11:11:11:11:11:11.
R: The router that has proxy ARP enabled. It doesn't have any IP address assigned in any of its 2 interfaces. The network interface connected to A is called eth_r_a and its MAC address is 22:22:22:22:22:22. The network interface connected to B is called eth_r_b and its MAC address is 33:33:33:33:33:33.
B: The server A wants to send IP packets to. eth_b_r's IP address = 4.4.4.4; MAC address = 44:44:44:44:44:44.

Let's also assume that a network administrator configured the following routing table entries in these devices:

A: Send packets with destination IP address prefixed with 4.4.4.0/24 through eth_a_r
R: Send packets with destination IP address prefixed with 1.1.1.0/24 through eth_r_a
R: Send packets with destination IP address prefixed with 4.4.4.0/24 through eth_r_b
B: Send packets with destination IP address prefixed with 1.1.1.0/24 through eth_b_r

I think I need a step by step explanation of what exactly would happen when trying to perform a proxy arp request without an ip address assigned in the router to see where it could fail. Something like this:

Do something
Do something else
Do something that actually involves the IP address of the router because you need it to do X but you can't because the interface doesn't have any IP address assigned.

This is what the step by step process of sending an IP packet from A to B looks like to me:

A user executes the command ping 4.4.4.4 from A.
In order to know the MAC address of the device with IP address 4.4.4.4, an ARP request is created with these fields:

Source hardware address: 11:11:11:11:11:11
Source protocol address: 1.1.1.1
Destination hardware address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Destination protocol address: 4.4.4.4


The ARP request is broadcasted through eth_a_r.
eth_r_a receives the request.
The router checks its routing table to see which interface it should use to forward the ARP request because it has Proxy ARP enabled.
The router finds a match and forwards the ARP request through eth_r_b because the ARP request is asking for 4.4.4.4.
eth_r_b broadcasts the ARP request.
eth_b_r receives the ARP request.
eth_b_r checks if it has the IP address 4.4.4.4 assigned.
eth_b_r creates an ARP response with his MAC address:

Source hardware address: 44:44:44:44:44:44
Source protocol address: 4.4.4.4
Destination hardware address: 11:11:11:11:11:11
Destination protocol address: 1.1.1.1


eth_b_r broadcasts the ARP response.
eth_r_b receives the ARP response.
The router checks its routing table and finds a match, so it forwards the ARP response through eth_r_a.
eth_r_a broadcasts the ARP response.
eth_a_r receives the ARP response.
eth_a_r checks if ARP's destination MAC address is the one that it has assigned.
The MAC addresses of the ARP response and the one it has assigned match, so it accepts the response.
A creates the IP packet. The destination MAC address is 44:44:44:44:44:44 and A knows it because it received this information from the ARP response that it received earlier.
A checks its routing table to know which network interface should it send the IP packet through for the destination IP address of 4.4.4.4 and finds a match.
eth_a_r sends the IP packet.
eth_r_a receives the packet.
The router checks its routing table, finds a match for the destination IP address of 4.4.4.4 because it has a prefix of 4.4.4.0/24 and sends the packet through eth_r_b without touching its MAC address because it already is the correct one: 44:44:44:44:44:44.
eth_b_r receives the IP packet. Hurray!

I have not made a single mention of eth_r_a's and eth_r_b's IP addresses because they are not needed at all. Therefore it shouldn't be necessary to have an IP address assigned in eth_r_b or eth_r_b.
Let's review the explanations given one by one:

Ron Maupin's answer:

The router would not be an IP router for that router interface because it would not know about the network directly connected to it.

But the router does know about the networks directly connected to it thanks to its routing table, so what exactly does he mean?

A router not having an IP address for an interface means that the router cannot use that interface for IP.

But I just showed how an IP packet can be sent through the router despite it not having any IP address so it can be used for IP. What am I misunderstanding here?

Putting an IP address (either IPv4 or IPv6) enables IP for that interface.

Maybe the system is configured in such a way that network interfaces that have no IP address assigned don't do anything at all. But that doesn't mean you can't route IP packets without an IP address, it just mean that you can't do that in that system in particular and because it is configured in such a way, not because it isn't possible per se.

Routers route packets between different networks, and a router that does not know how to reach a network will drop any packets destined for that network.

This router doesn't need to have any IP address assigned in any of its network interfaces to know how to reach each network. It just need a routing table to know which network interface to forward packets to.

The IP address on the router interface tells the router how to reach that network.

But I thought it was the routing table what was being used to know how to reach the networks? How exactly would the router use the network interface's IP address instead of (or with) its routing table to determine which network interface should it forward IP packets to?

Jeremy Impson's answer:

The other aspect you ask about is why the router needs an IP address in order to provide routing service. In general, a router needs to know what networks are locally connected to it.

But again, how exactly are you even supposed to use the network interface's IP address instead (or with) the routing table?

It needs this information so that, when attempting to deliver a packet, it can know when and if it should use the Layer 2 network service to deliver the frame, or if it should to a next hop route (whether static, learned, or last resort). This is just like any other IP processing node.

What exactly are the steps involving the decision of "when and if it should use the Layer 2 network service to deliver the frame, or if it should to a next hop route", and in which of those steps is the network interface's IP address used and how?

So you could invent some other way for a router to understand when a packet gets local delivery or is forwarded, one that doesn't require it having an IP address.

But I didn't have to invent anything new, I just used the routing table entries to make the decisions.

Zac67:

A node without IP address isn't reachable. When you can't reach the gateway, the route isn't usable.

I don't need to reach the router itself, I only need to reach the things that are on the other side of the router.

On the other hand, if a router has no IP address on one of its interfaces, how is it supposed to know when to answer to ARP requests on another interface, ie. which addresses are actually local to it when other routers proxy remote addresses?

I am not 100% sure I understand what you mean. I'm going to assume that, in my scenario, eth_r_b has some IP address assigned and A wants to learn its MAC address. Then the router would perform as follow:

eth_r_a receives the ARP request.
The router itself checks if any of its network interfaces has the requested IP address assigned. If there is any, answer with its MAC address. If there is none, forward the request. That is, if the one answering the ARP request is the device itself.

If ARP requests are only meant to be answered by network interfaces (and not the devices they are attached to) then I can see the problem here. It makes sense to think that it is the network interface and not the device the one supposed to answer the ARP request, otherwise the device might as well answer also for other IP addresses that are assigned to other network interfaces that are connected to a different network.
Therefore, the only devices that could reach that network interface itself are the ones connected to the same side of the router of that network interface. This is, so far, the only explanation that makes sense to me, even though technically speaking it still seems like you only need IP addresses assigned to each interface to be able to reach the router itself and nothing else, so you can still ARP the devices of each side of the router anyways.



If the router has no IP address on any interface, then how does it use ARP to get the MAC addresses in order to be able to proxy ARP for the connected networks? Also, it will not have any entries in its routing table, so it is not a router. Basically, you have a bridge, not a router.

I understand what you mean with your first point, but what do you mean when you say "it will not have any entries in its routing table"? You configure the routing table manually, you don't need IP addresses assigned in eth_r_a or eth_r_b for that. Maybe you meant the router wouldn't have any entry in its own ARP cache? in that case then it makes sense.

Manually configuring routes does not scale. Taking a router, with no addresses on any interface and only configuring proxy ARP leaves it with no entries in its routing table. You could not get a routing protocol to work without IP addresses, so the only way to get any routes in the routing table would be configuring static entries, and that does not scale and. it is not dynamic, so it cannot automatically adjust to routing changes.

@RonMaupin: I tested this during our earlier discussion, and I saw my router (which had no IPv4 addresses) sending ARP requests from 0.0.0.0 and other hosts responding to such ARP requests as normal. You're right that manually configuring routes doesn't scale, but 1) scaleability wasn't quite the question in the first place; manually configuring routes is possible and allows the router to forward packets regardless, and 2) IS-IS comes to mind, being a routing protocol that functions without IP... I have no hardware to test IS-IS with, but I suspect it would do the job here.

@u1686_grawity, so neither the A nor the B side of the router had an IP address? You cannot have a default route going toward both the A and B sides of the router. That means it is no longer a router, but a bridge. Routing is at layer-3 (IP address), but bridging is at layer-2 (MAC address). Your "router" is simply bridging by MAC address.

@RonMaupin: I never said I have a default route on both interfaces (or either interface for that matter), the only 0.0.0.0 I've mentioned was the source address field of an ARP query. I'm aware of the difference between bridging and routing; I specifically tested L3 routes and watched the packets go where the IP routing table directs them.

I just realized where the problem is.
Basically, when the router receives the ARP request from A to know the MAC address of the device with IP address of 4.4.4.4, the router is supposed to answer that ARP request with it's own MAC address because otherwise when eth_r_2 receives the IP packet that A initially wanted to send, it will see that its MAC address doesn't match the MAC address of the IP packet and discard it. The only way eth_r_2 would accept the IP packet is by answering the ARP request from before with its own MAC address.
Now here is the real step by step process:

A sends ARP request
R receives the request
R changes the MAC address of the ARP request to its own one
R changes the IP address of the ARP request to its own one. Problem: R doesn't have any IP address assigned, so you can't proceed from here. But even if you did (for instance, keeping A's IP address instead even though you are supposed to replace the IP address too because from here on it is the router that is doing the ARP request)...
R forwards the ARP request
B receives the APR request and answers accordingly
R receives B's answer
R replaces the destination MAC address with A's one. Wait, hold on, how does the router know that MAC address? Easy, just send an ARP request from the router with these values:

Destination MAC address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Destination IP address: 1.1.1.1
Source MAC address: 22:22:22:22:22:22
Source IP address: <enter surprised pikachu face here>



Yes, I know, you could technically also answer that last ARP request the router does to know A's MAC address filling the source IP address with B's, but at this point it kinda feels like a bit of a stretch doesn't it? Specially when you are doing all of this only for the sake of not having an IP address assigned in eth_r_a and eth_r_b. Is that how the router is supposed to behave, as if when it had no IP address assigned it pretended to have all IP address of the other side of the router assigned to itself just to work? And all of this just because I don't want to assign an IP address? No thanks.
Let's keep with the process anyways to see what happens next:

A gets the router's ARP answer.
A sends its IP packet. It has R's MAC address on it.
R receives the IP packet.
R checks the routing table and decides to forward the IP packet through eth_r_b.
R replaces the source MAC address of the IP packet with eth_r_b's.
R checks its own ARP cache to know what MAC address should go in the destination MAC address of the IP packet that is destined to 2.2.2.2.
R doesn't find anything in its ARP cache, so it tries to send an ARP request.
R gets depressed because it can't create an ARP request to know B's MAC address because eth_r_b doesn't have any IP address assigned.

Again, you could technically use A's IP address to create the ARP request, but that is just wrong because that's not the IP address that you are supposed to use, and it doesn't make sense to create routers capable of doing this when it is so wrong and no one does things this way, only for the sake of not having to assign an IP address. Might as well use a bridge at this point, really.

A (1.1.1.1 and presumably a sane network size like /24) would never send an ARP to find 4.4.4.4 because it is not part of its connected network segment. Operating systems don't ARP for every IP address in the known universe, only for IP addresses on their own connected networks. Anything else requires a specific route for the destination network (in this case it might be 4.4.4.0/24 via 1.1.1.254) or a default route like 0.0.0.0/0 via 1.1.1.254 in either case the only ARP done would be to find the MAC of 1.1.1.254 and send traffic to the gateway/router (which requires and IP on its interfaces).

@FrameHowitzer This video shows an example at 6:18 where a computer is, in fact, ARPing every IP address in the known universe. I mean, not all of them, only the ones it ever needs to send data to. I think that 1.1.1.1 would send an ARP to find 4.4.4.4 because the only way to know if it is in the same network segment is by checking the routing table, and I don't think network interfaces do that when ARPing. Also, technically speaking you could configure a network with /0.

Well yes, because they badly misconfigured the router by routing all IP addresses to a local interface. That would never work on an actual normal internet connection. The service provider would see it as an attack and shut off the connection. So yes, it would do that if you intentionally configure your equipment wrong... but you'd never connect to anything so, why would you do that?

@FrameHowitzer, you could replace that with 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24 and just assume A and B are configured with /23 masks. That would make it much more feasible than treating 0/0 as on-link.

@Adrian, in step 8, R already knows A's MAC address, since it was in the ARP request A sent initially in step 1. All it needs to do to answer is fill the missing field and swap src and dest around. (I have the impression real systems might also pick up ARP mappings from ARP requests, but I might be wrong.) And since your router is just acting as an ARP-middleman here, it might as well pass A's ARP request to B with A's IP address as the source. Why not, since you are faking they'd be directly connected.

But without an IP address, R would have a hard time communicating itself, and in real networks, it just might need to. Think software updates, traceroutes, routing protocols etc. And yes, you're right that for the basic forwarding operation, one could specify a (default) gw with just the MAC address. But I suppose it's usually done with an IP address just to keep everything on that layer, the L2 addresses being a bit of a low-level detail in that sense.

But for many purposes, it's enough for R to have an IP address, it might not really need one for each interface. You'll just have to do some uncommon configuration and people will go "you can't do that!" even if you show it to them in action. :) Some systems support "unnumbered" interfaces in some cases, but yes, you run the risk of some OS causing issues in others. You'll also find (if you already didn't) that networkengineering.SE isn't really a community interested in discussing unorthodox ideas. You tend to get very stiff responses if you try to skirt the boundaries of what's possible.

@ilkkachu: Coincidentally, I found this among open tabs: https://ublog.tech/@IPngNetworks/113532868362352360 (I think that's one of the SiXXS cofounders?) – example of a Tbps production network with IPv4 routed entirely via IPv6 link-local nexthops. Apparently the router management (SSH, updates, etc) runs over IPv6 using a loopback address. (Looks like the setup uses VPP so it's kind of a special case, but I know the same mechanism is doable with baseline Linux, and with any other Linux-based platform – seen it mentioned in Juniper documentation as well.)

@u1686_grawity, oh, thanks for the link! I know what I'm doing at work tomorrow...

ARP is a layer 3 protocol.
If a router doesn't have an IP address on an interface it functions as a L2 device forwarding frames based on L2 headers.
So, if an IP address isn't configured the router doesn't even look at headers beyond layer 2.

That's not true, in at least two different ways: 1) such an interface will more likely not forward anything at all – unless explicitly bridged with another interface, 2) in practice there exist plenty of router platforms where interfaces without IP addresses do forward at IP layer, as was discussed in other comment threads over the last few days.

I guess that depends on specific implementation. When I implemented data plane features on BCM chips interfaces on ingress only affected ingress filtering. The interfaces were part of a L2(VSI) or a L3(VRF) service which determined how to process the frame. In case the interface is part of a L2 service the lookup was performed in VSI Mac table, and the frame was transmitted based on this lookup resolution- and that's it. sometimes there are special cases where packets do get trapped to CPU for special handling. Maybe there are some implementations where they allow trapping ARP packets from L2

I think the point is that interfaces can still be in "L3 service" mode despite not having any IP addresses assigned.
